# Angular2 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys

Tags: google-maps, angular

I am trying Google maps api with Angular2 (Angular 2 Directives for Google Maps https://angular-maps.com/).

I managed to get my sample working without any error. but I do see one warning in browse's console -

```
"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"
```

What I need to do go away this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code-

```
import {provideLazyMapsAPILoaderConfig, GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,
  provideLazyMapsAPILoaderConfig({ apiKey: 'yourKey', clientId: 'yourClientId' })
])
```

See if this helps.